# How can I completely remove TinyMCE in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

When I say "remove," I mean "permanently remove, forever, for everybody." All I want is a plain vanilla text box to paste HTML into, which I am editing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing can be really be permanent as it's part of the core and updates will likely re-enable it at some point.

You can try adding `add_filter ( 'user_can_richedit' , create_function ( '$a' , 'return false;' ) , 50 );` to your functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You may set the tinymce configuration parameter [mode](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3amode) to `none`.

This means a special command is needed in order to initaialize the editor, thus your textarea will stay as it is.

Comment: This worked, thanks!  More complete instructions for doing this for Wordpress noobs: https://gist.github.com/3812604

Comment: Except to do that you have to edit within /wp-includes/ - which will almost always get overwritten when an update is applied.