# Can't deactivate TinyMCE plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

The problem is, I activated recently the **TinyMCE Advanced** plugin for my WordPress webpage.

The person that keeps updating the page didn't get used to the plugin, so I intended to deactivate **TinyMCE** and activate the plugin we were using previously.

The problem is, I deactivated, even uninstalled the **TinyMCE** plugin, but it keeps functioning like nothing has happened.

Anyone could enlighten me?

Comment: The question seems duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648402/how-can-i-completely-remove-tinymce-in-wordpress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I completely remove TinyMCE in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648402/how-can-i-completely-remove-tinymce-in-wordpress)